# reader.readLine() of BufferedReader causes this: Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Stream closed

Tags: java, bufferedreader

Here is a code snippet from my main Java function:

```
try (MultiFileReader multiReader = new MultiFileReader(inputs)) {
        PriorityQueue<WordEntry> words = new PriorityQueue<>();
        for (BufferedReader reader : multiReader.getReaders()) {
            String word = reader.readLine();
            if (word != null) {
                words.add(new WordEntry(word, reader));
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is how I get my BufferedReader readers from another Java file:

```
public List<BufferedReader> getReaders() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(readers);
    }
```

But for some reason, when I compile my code here is what I get:

[image: This is the error generated when I compile my code]

The error happens exactly at the line where I wrote `String word = reader.readLine();` and what's weird is that `reader.readLine()` is not null, in fact `multiReader.getReaders()` returns a list of 100 objects (they are files read from a directory). I would like some help solving that issue.

I posted where the issue is, now let me provide a broader view of my code. To run it, it suffices to compile it under the src/ directory doing `javac *.java` and `java MergeShards shards/ sorted.txt` provided that `shards/` is present under `src/` and contains `.txt` files in my scenario.

- This is `MergeShards.java` where I have my main function:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public final class MergeShards {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        if (args.length != 2) {
            System.out.println("Usage: MergeShards [input folder] [output file]");
            return;
        }

        List<Path> inputs = Files.walk(Path.of(args[0]), 1).skip(1).collect(Collectors.toList());
        Path outputPath = Path.of(args[1]);

        try (MultiFileReader multiReader = new MultiFileReader(inputs)) {
            PriorityQueue<WordEntry> words = new PriorityQueue<>();
            for (BufferedReader reader : multiReader.getReaders()) {
                String word = reader.readLine();
                if (word != null) {
                    words.add(new WordEntry(word, reader));
                }
            }

            try (Writer writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(outputPath)) {
                while (!words.isEmpty()) {
                    WordEntry entry = words.poll();
                    writer.write(entry.word);
                    writer.write(System.lineSeparator());
                    String word = entry.reader.readLine();
                    if (word != null) {
                        words.add(new WordEntry(word, entry.reader));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static final class WordEntry implements Comparable<WordEntry> {
        private final String word;
        private final BufferedReader reader;

        private WordEntry(String word, BufferedReader reader) {
            this.word = Objects.requireNonNull(word);
            this.reader = Objects.requireNonNull(reader);
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(WordEntry other) {
            return word.compareTo(other.word);
        }
    }
}
```

- This is my `MultiFileReader.java` file:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.Closeable;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public final class MultiFileReader implements Closeable {

    private final List<BufferedReader> readers;

    public MultiFileReader(List<Path> paths) {
        readers = new ArrayList<>(paths.size());
        try {
            for (Path path : paths) {
                readers.add(Files.newBufferedReader(path));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            close();
        }
    }

    public List<BufferedReader> getReaders() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(readers);
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        for (BufferedReader reader : readers) {
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (Exception ignored) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post close() method of MultiFileReader? cuz the close method will be called after the try block. try-with-resource

Comment: @wuhoyt I just edited the code to post it

Comment: after the try block, the close method of MultiFileReader was called and all the readers are closed.

Comment: @wuhoyt You are right, but am I not supposed to call the close method since it avoids memory leaks?

Comment: I was wrong, and @Elliott was right, the close() call in the constructor should be removed and probably just that. And the close should be call manually or autoly by the machine after use the obj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `finally` block in your constructor closes all of your readers. Remove that.

```
public MultiFileReader(List<Path> paths) {
    readers = new ArrayList<>(paths.size());
    try {
        for (Path path : paths) {
            readers.add(Files.newBufferedReader(path));
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } /* Not this. finally {
        close();
    } */
}
```

Comment: It works when I remove the `close();` method I called from the finally block but am I not supposed to close all my readers to avoid memory leaks?

Comment: @EbillsonGRANDJEAN Well, yes you should close it when you're done _using_ it, but that code is just setting up a list of `BufferedReader` for use _somewhere else_. Your code is closing each reader before it gets used.

Comment: @EbillsonGRANDJEAN You are *correctly* closing it with a `try-with-Resources` here `try (MultiFileReader multiReader = new MultiFileReader(inputs)) {`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Oh yes!, you are right about that, `try-with-resources` does the closing job